# How to deny users and redirect to login page when they type the same url in web page

Tags: asp.net

After login I enter into the Librarianform. Now when I copy the url and paste it in new tab it's showing the page without login. So I want to redirect the users to login page when they copy and paste the url. How to do that.Can you please explain it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET has a login mechanism you can use. To enable it, add the below in your `web.config` file. Change the `loginUrl` attribute to the path of your own login page.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx" timeout="28800" name="webappname" />
        </authentication>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

To create the ASP.NET authentication cookie you need to call the `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` as you can see below

```
string username = "";
bool rememberme = true;

// Implement your own login mechanism and if the user is authenticated
// set the username to the variable and make this call below
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, rememberme);
```

Finally, to logout a user you can simply call

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

You can also see this [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-User-Login-Form-example-in-ASPNet.aspx), which describes a similar mechanism

Answer (score 0):

NO. YOU CAN'T MAKE USER TO LOGIN EVERY TIME WHILE REQUESTING PAGE

That's the way  `Authentication` works in `asp.net` or in any web application so that user no need to authenticate for every page once he has been authenticated.

Hope you're using `Forms Authentication`. By default `Form Authentication` uses `Cookies` to store `SessionID` ,

You can use `cookieless` `authentication` by setting below values in `web.config` file

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState cookieless="true"
      regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

> ASP.NET maintains cookieless session state by automatically inserting
>   a unique session ID into the page's URL.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.140%29.aspx.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2796/Cookieless-ASP-NET-forms-authentication